# How do I pass the value of a session variable to $.ajax()?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net-4.0

I have a session variable containing some string data. How do I access the session variable from the markup (not the code behind) and pass its value to the following code? I need to replace the ?????  with the actual value of the session variable. Thanks!

```
function btnAddTask_onclick() {
            var inputData = { task: $(".taskInput").val(), sessionVar: ????? };

            $.ajax({
                "url": "AddTask.aspx",
                "type": "get",
                "data": inputData, 
                "success": function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                    $("body").append(response);

                },
                "error": function (response) {
                    alert("Error: " + response);
                }
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var inputData = { task: $(".taskInput").val(), sessionVar: '<%= Session["session_var"] %>' }
```

Answer (score 2):

@Carlos M's answer is good, assuming that the data you need from session is up to date at the time the button is clicked. But since you're using Ajax, I'm going to assume that is not necessarily true, e.g. some other previous ajaxified action on the client could have caused `Session` to change.

What I can't help wondering, though, is what purpose does passing session data directly to an ajax request serve? Why don't you just access `Session` directly from your code in `AddTask.aspx` instead having the server render something on the client, only to pass it right back to the server? It doesn't seem as if there's any purpose in accessing `Session` on the client, since all  you do is pass it to the server again. It's not actually used at the client.

Comment: Good point. I'm fairly new to web development and appreciate the information.